# Из массива строк (формат время и дата) как преобразовать

Tags: java, android, дата

Я получаю массив таких вот дат и времени из сервера,

```
String[] format = {"2017-01-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC",
                   "2017-01-27 22:00:00 +0000 UTC",
                   "2017-01-27 15:00:00 +0000 UTC",
                   "2017-01-27 19:00:00 +0000 UTC"};
```

как получить в приложении текущую время и дату , преобразовать этот массив c изменениями в тот часовой пояс которое у пользователя .

Comment: Еще раз с самого начала, ничего не понял что нужно сделать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String[] format = { "2017-01-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC", "2017-01-27 22:00:00 +0000 UTC",
            "2017-01-27 15:00:00 +0000 UTC", "2017-01-27 19:00:00 +0000 UTC" };
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z");
    for (int i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(format[i]));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected data from server", e);
        }
    }
```

В конструктор new SimpleDateFormat можете подсунуть требуемую локаль, в противном случае, используется `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , а можете подсказать после изменения даты и времени , можно как то записать в массив , но{
Пт янв  27 03:00:00} вот таким форматами без (+0000 UTC) и на русском ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
String[] dates = {
            "2017-01-27 00:00:00 +0000 UTC",
            "2017-01-27 22:00:00 +0000 UTC",
            "2017-01-27 15:00:00 +0000 UTC",
            "2017-01-27 19:00:00 +0000 UTC"};

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendOffset("+HHmm", "0000")
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendZoneId()
            .toFormatter();

for (String date : dates)
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime
                .parse(date,formatter)
                .toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .format(formatter));
```

Вывод будет такой:

> 2017-01-27 04:00:00 +04 Europe/Samara
>   2017-01-28 02:00:00 +04 Europe/Samara
>   2017-01-27 19:00:00 +04 Europe/Samara
>   2017-01-27 23:00:00 +04 Europe/Samara

Comment: я бы добавил что Ваш вариант работает только с Java 8

Comment: А я бы добавил, что ваш пример работает только с java 1.2 . Вот только зачем это уточнение?

Comment: К сожалению, не все еще перешли на 1.8... согласитесь, что уже вряд-ли кто работает на 1.1 :)

Comment: Я отталкиваюсь всегда от того, что если автор вопроса не уточняет, значит можно использовать любую версию. Насчет тех, кто не перешел, я могу им только посочувствовать - 1.9 уже на носу.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov извините но DateTimeFormatter подчеркивает красным

Comment: @Serg  начните писать на java 8

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov у меня java 8 но в android Studio DateTimeFormatter подчеркивает красным

Comment: не силен в андройде, но там вроде как нет полноценной java 8